# Cyclically dependent question which includes cyclic dependencies.

Tags: discussion

So here is a fun one.

This question and answer:

[Why aren't my include guards preventing recursive inclusion and multiple symbol definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909997/why-arent-my-include-guards-preventing-recursive-inclusion-and-multiple-symbol)

Has a link as part of the answer `What they are not protecting you from is multiple definitions in separate translation units. This is also explained in this Q&A on StackOverflow.`. This link points to here:

[Why include guards do not prevent multiple function definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425262/why-include-guards-do-not-prevent-multiple-function-definitions/14425299#14425299)

Which has been marked as a duplicate back to the original question. How do you handle that one?

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem that needs to be handled? The link is to *an actual answer*. That answer is still there, and still contains the advertised information. Seems all is fine to me.

Comment: No problem, thats why i tagged it as a discussion! So i guess your answer could be, you dont handle it, that is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two questions are duplicates and the duplicity is only identified after answers have been given to both then it can happen that good, useful answers to the one common question are distributed over both instances.

I think the official stance is to leave everything like it is. And indeed the quoted answer links to an answer of the duplicate question, not to the question itself (which is a duplicate).

Btw. one could think about moving all the useful answers to one canonical question and have the duplicate questions only stand without any answers in order to make life easier for the visitor so he doesn't have to read several questions to get all relevant answers but then questions which are marked for duplicates may not be a 100% identical and anyway this would be more like a job for moderators, wouldn't it.

Comment: Actually, the *official* stance is that all info from the closed question should be added to the duplication-target, so as many people as possible will benefit from it (Don't forget mentioning the source where appropriate). Anyone seeing it could do so by posting their own answer / suggesting refinements to existing answers. (If appropriate, one can suggest the moderators should merge the questions)

Comment: @Deduplicator The first part of that is right, but the second isn't. Moderators have the ability to *merge* a duplicate question with another question, which automatically transfers all of the answers. That means you don't have to *repost* them, which eliminates the problem of having to give credit. And better yet, it actually ensures that the original poster gets the reputation she is due. Flag duplicate questions (with good answers) for merger if appropriate. (Edit: Oh, hey. You say that eventually. Oh well.)

Comment: @CodyGray I wonder why this is done so seldom? Most duplicates I encounter are not merged and answers are scattered.

Comment: Because they have to be manually flagged for merger, and a moderator has to agree with and process your flag. Not all questions are suitable for merging, but there are quite a few that it would be appropriate for.